# IntelliJ run configurations in build.gradle file

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle project which I can currently import into IntelliJ via the `build.gradle` file. IntelliJ will setup the correct source locations and pull in the dependencies for me.

What I would like to do is list the IntelliJ "run configurations" in the `build.gradle` file so it will automatically set these up for me (correct class/arguments). Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean when you say *run configuration*?

Comment: Top-right hand corner, it lists the run configurations. If I goto the main class, right-click -> "Run" it will create a run configuration for me with no args etc......I want one created by default when I import the gradle project with the correct args etc....see here for what run configurations are: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: It's not possible, related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174087.

Answer (score 3):

There is an experimental plugin for Gradle developed by an employee of JetBrains.

https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin

It provides several options to adjust the configuration of IntelliJ from within the build-script. Adding a *run configuration* could look like this.

```
plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext" version "0.5"
}

idea.project.settings.runConfigurations {
  'App'(org.jetbrains.gradle.ext.Application) {
    mainClass = 'com.example.myapp.App'
    moduleName = project.idea.module.name + '.main'
    programParameters = '--some-option some-argument'
    jvmArgs = '-Xmx1G'
  }
}
```

Comment: I had some issues to get the plugin going, possibly due to the disagreement between Gradle versions in and outside IDEA. It is still finicky - some things appear to work, others appear to work sometimes (such as the sample JUnit run config - it does appear in IDEA but very rarely). Unsure as to why...

Comment: I only tested *run configurations* so far. I worked well at this point but it was some time ago. Maybe I can try it out tomorrow with recent versions of *IntellJ* and *Gradle*.

Comment: @Learner, I just tested it with version 2019.3.4 of IntelliJ and version 6.3 of Gradle. At least my example worked as expected without a problem. However, it is a side project of an employee and not officially supported. I guess there might be issues with some features.